# I am using Apache POI to create header and footer in docx but the resulting file cannot be opened

Tags: java, apache-poi, footer, docx, xwpf

I am using Apache POI to create header and footer but the resulting file cannot be opened.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eDGcF.png

```
XWPFDocument  docx = new XWPFDocument();
CTP ctpFooter = CTP.Factory.newInstance();
ctpFooter.addNewR().addNewT();

XWPFParagraph footerParagraph = new XWPFParagraph(ctpFooter, docx);
XWPFRun footerRun = footerParagraph.createRun();
footerRun.setFontSize(6);
footerRun.setText("footerText");
XWPFParagraph[] parsFooter = new XWPFParagraph[1];
parsFooter[0] = footerParagraph;

CTSectPr sectPr = docx.getDocument().getBody().addNewSectPr();
XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy policy = new XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy(docx, sectPr);
policy.createFooter(XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy.DEFAULT, parsFooter);

FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("E:/docx/write-test.docx");
docx.write(out);
out.close();
```

Comment: This code is misusing the `CT*` classes. Using the current `apache poi` versions this is not more needed. There is a `BetterHeaderFooterExample.java` in https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/poi-examples/src/main/java/org/apache/poi/examples/xwpf/usermodel/ which shows how to create header/footer now.

Comment: What `apache poi` version?

Comment: version  apache poi 3.9

Comment: Sorry, that version is too old. Nobody should use that ancient version in 2022.

Comment: Thinking about it haha